# Can we use custom authentication method in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am making an app whic require role base login so can we use any other authentication method like

- Id number
- Date of birth
- login and password

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth?authuser=0), you can "integrate Firebase Authentication with a custom authentication system by modifying your authentication server to produce [**custom signed tokens**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens?authuser=0) when a user successfully signs in."

Note that Firebase Authentication already offers authentication through login and password. More precisely through email addresses and passwords, as presented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth?authuser=0. However, in case you want to use a login that is not an email (e.g. to use an existing LDAP) you'll have to use the integration referred to above.